# Which algorithm do DGGEV or DSYGV Eigen solvers in LAPACK implement? Is it 'QZ' algorithm which MATLAB uses?

Tags: c++, matlab, linear-algebra, lapack, eigenvalue

Which algorithm do DGGEV or DSYGV Eigen solvers in LAPACK implement? Is it 'QZ' algorithm which MATLAB uses?

http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d9/d52/dggev_8f_source.html

http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d5/d2e/dsygv_8f.html

Does anybody know where can I find implementation of **QZ algorithm** (*generalized* Schur decomposition) to calculate Eigen values & vectors in C++?

---

EDIT:

I implemented some of LAPACK routines and mentioned some observations in this link:

https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/16220/eigenvectors-matlab-vs-lapack-dggev-or-dggevx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MATLAB used to have a list of LAPACK rountine used by `eig` function in its documentation, but decided to remove it for some reason.

Here is a screenshot of the table from the [archived docs of R2009a](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2009a/techdoc/ref/eig.html):

> [image: eig_algorithms]

I can't guarantee things haven't changed since then.

---

## EDIT:

The doc page of the [`qz` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2009a/techdoc/ref/qz.html) had a similar table of LAPACK rountines:

> [image: qz_algorithm]

---

For reference, you could also look at how other scientific frameworks implement this function:

- **Octave**: Has the equivalent [`qz` function](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/qz.html). Here is the source code: http://hg.octave.org/octave/file/tip/libinterp/corefcn/qz.cc
- **SciPy**: Also implements the [generalized Schur decomposition](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.qz.html). [You can see](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/linalg/_decomp_qz.py#L202) it also ends up calling [DGGES](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/db/ddb/dgges_8f.html) from LAPACK.
- **Julia**: Here is a reference to Julia's implementation of [Schur decomposition](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/linalg/?highlight=schur#Base.schur): https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/linalg/factorization.jl#L697‌​, https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/linalg/lapack.jl#L3358
- **R**: Here is an equivalent R package for generalized eigenvalue problem. You can inspect the source code: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geigen/index.html

Comment: I wonder if I can contact Mathworks and ask them which LAPACK subroutines they are calling to do `qz` Eigen analysis in newest version of MATLAB. Will they answer?

Comment: Maybe in the newer version of MATLAB they are using some methods like the one explained in this [webpage](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node56.html) which calls 3 subroutines of LAPACK to do Eigen analysis with `qz`. I'm not sure. I want to directly call LAPACK subroutines in my C++ code, but I'm not sure which subroutines to call. Maybe the only way to go is by trial & error to see which subroutines generate the exact MATLAB results for ill-conditioned input matrices (I deal with ill-conditioned matrices and that's the major challenge). I would be happy to hear any comment on this. Thanks.

Comment: @user3853917: oh, for some reason I though you were asking about the EIG function.. See my edit, I added a similar screenshot taken from the R2009 archived doc of `qz` function.

Comment: @user3853917: here is a related question: [Schur(QZ) Decomposition Differences](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/14607/386)

Comment: For a bit of history, up to v5 MATLAB used routines from EISPACK to compute the [QZ decomposition](http://cens.ioc.ee/local/man/matlab/techdoc/ref/qz.html), but that later got replaced with LAPACK routines starting with v6 (around year 2000): http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matlab-incorporates-lapack.html